# Custom Dialog from SQLite data

Tags: android, sqlite, dialog

I (think) I have managed to build most of the code required to display SQLite data in a custom dialog but am still stuck on how to put it all together.

My Adaptor looks like this:

```
public class ScoresDisplayerAdaptor extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    public ScoresDisplayerAdaptor(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.playerscoresrow, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

    /**
     * @author will
     * 
     * @param   v
     *          The view in which the elements we set up here will be displayed.
     * 
     * @param   context
     *          The running context where this ListView adapter will be active.
     * 
     * @param   c
     *          The Cursor containing the query results we will display.
     */

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        int player1Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_SCORE));
        int player2Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER2_SCORE));
        int player3Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER3_SCORE));
        int player4Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER4_SCORE));

        /**
         * Next set the title of the entry.
         */

        TextView tvwPlayer1Score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer1score);
        TextView tvwPlayer2Score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer2score);
        TextView tvwPlayer3Score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer3score);
        TextView tvwPlayer4Score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvwPlayer4score);
        tvwPlayer1Score.setText(player1Score);
        tvwPlayer2Score.setText(player2Score);
        tvwPlayer3Score.setText(player3Score);
        tvwPlayer4Score.setText(player4Score);
    }


}
```

My XMLs:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>
<Table>
<TableRow>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer4score" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>
</Table>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, my code where I use it is like this:

```
private void showCurrentScores(){

    DBAdaptor dbAdaptor;
    Cursor scoresCursor;
    ScoresDisplayerAdaptor scoresDisplayerAdaptor;  

    dbAdaptor = new DBAdaptor(this);
    scoresCursor = dbAdaptor.getScores();

    startManagingCursor(scoresCursor);

    scoresDisplayerAdaptor = new ScoresDisplayerAdaptor(this,scoresCursor);

}
```

But I am stuck now what to put after that last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first answer here ...
[Simple display of data from SQlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625862/simple-display-of-data-from-sqlite-database) or
here [Custom listviews, 3 Strings per item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551900/custom-listviews-3-strings-per-item)

well ... were not bad, but it were like killing mosquito with shotgun

you don't need to build your own Adapter for that

just use SimpleCursorAdapter

```
dbAdaptor = new DBAdaptor(this);
//!!!!remeber scroresCursor MUST have "_id" column
scoresCursor = dbAdaptor.getScores();
listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
//this is itemrow.xml
R.layout.itemrow,
scoresCursor , 
//"from" this is array of columns 
new String[]{DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER1_SCORE, DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER2_SCORE, DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER3_SCORE, DBAdaptor.KEY_PLAYER4_SCORE},
//"to" next goes ids in itemrow.xml, values from "from" columns are mapped to "to" Views
new int[] {R.id.tvwPlayer1score, R.id.tvwPlayer2score, R.id.tvwPlayer3score, R.id.tvwPlayer4score }));
```

next: are you able to display this data in listview in activity (not dialog) ?

EDIT:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogus);
    ListView lv = (ListView)dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            Cursor c = managedQuery(
            Uri.parse("content://selvin.ListSyncSample/List"),
            new String[] { "_id",  "Name",
                "Description", "CreatedDate"  }, null,
            null, "Name");
    lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, cursor, new String[] { "Name",
            "Description", "CreatedDate" }, new int[] {
            R.id.tName, R.id.tDescription, R.id.tCreatedDate }));
    dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
    dialog.show();
```

itemrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tName" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tDescription" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_below="@id/tName" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tCreatedDate" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_below="@id/tDescription"
        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="marquee" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_dialogus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

instead of Cursor c = managedQuery ... use your cursor

Comment: i'd rather not open a new activity. This is a score screen which is shown after every hand and I would rather have it showing as a dialog so we can see the game behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Where's your activity?  The activity is the "screen" that will be displayed.